# In Excell Data Validation can you conditionally force a "List" or not a list ("Any Value")?

Tags: excel

So

If Cell(A1) = "Rent" then 
   Data Validation should force Cell(A2) to be a pull-down list of all my rentors.

If Cell(A1) <> "Rent"
   Data Validation should allow Cell(A2) to be any value

I see in Data Validation I can make a Cell choose amongst lists based on another Cell.  In fact I have: Data Validation Allow: "List" & Formula: "=INDIRECT(A1)".  But that only allows various lists.  It does not allow a list or conditionally no list (any value).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this I can think of would be to use a macro. As an important note, if you needed to pick the drop-down list members based on a different cell value, you COULD do that without a macro.